How to retrieve Active Directory user information like Jobtitle, Department etc... in an offline ndts.dit and SystemHive
I have this script but it does not extract any attributes like Company, Title:
# Import the DSInternals module
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\DSInternals"

# Define file paths
$NTDSFile = "D:\Sysback\ADBackup\NTDS.dit"
$SYSTEMHive = "D:\Sysback\RegistryBackup\SYSTEM"
$outputPath = "F:\UserPersonnelInfo.csv"

# Extract the boot key from the SYSTEM hive
Write-Host "Extracting the boot key from the SYSTEM hive..."
$bootKey = Get-BootKey -SystemHivePath $SYSTEMHive

# Extract Active Directory accounts and attributes
Write-Host "Extracting user attributes from NTDS.dit..."
$accounts = Get-ADDBAccount -All -DBPath $NTDSFile -BootKey $bootKey

# Select personnel attributes
Write-Host "Selecting personnel attributes..."
$selectedAccounts = $accounts | Where-Object { $_.PrimaryGroupId -eq 513 } | # User accounts only
    Select-Object `
        SamAccountName, `
        DistinguishedName, `
        @{Name='Company'; Expression={($_.Attributes['company'])}}, `
        @{Name='Title'; Expression={($_.Attributes['title'])}}, `
        @{Name='Department'; Expression={($_.Attributes['department'])}}, `
        @{Name='StreetAddress'; Expression={($_.Attributes['streetAddress'])}}, `
        @{Name='City'; Expression={($_.Attributes['l'])}}, `
        @{Name='State'; Expression={($_.Attributes['st'])}}, `
        @{Name='PostalCode'; Expression={($_.Attributes['postalCode'])}}, `
        @{Name='Country'; Expression={($_.Attributes['c'])}}

# Export to CSV
Write-Host "Exporting personnel data to $outputPath..."
$selectedAccounts | Export-Csv -Path $outputPath -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "Extraction completed successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green

Is there any way to obtain such info from ntds.dit? Another way?
Or am I doing it wrong in attribute names?

Did you try dsamain.exe tool? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc772168(v=ws.11)#examples
